# where clause error of Unknown column

Tags: mysql

Below is the code type into databases.

```
CREATE TABLE customerlist
    (
      C_Id INT auto_increment,
      LoginID VARCHAR(10),
      Password VARCHAR(20) ,
      Name VARCHAR(20),
      Phone VARCHAR(15),
      IDCARDNO VARCHAR(15),
      Email VARCHAR(30),
      BankACNO VARCHAR(18),
      Plan VARCHAR(4),
      Date VARCHAR,
      PRIMARY KEY (C_Id),
      UNIQUE (LoginID)
    );

    insert into customerlist  values( 'A1','123','peter','123456','88888','abc@yahoo.com','1231','three','2014-01-12');
```

but when i type `select * from customerlist where LoginID = A1;`
it have error : `Unknown column 'A1' in 'where clause'`

how to solve it clearly ?thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare field with it's value then compare like `fieldName = "value"` as given below.

```
SELECT * FROM customerlist WHERE LoginID = "A1";
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem then accept answer for future user reference.